# AWS with Terraform - security groups argument inside a security group rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

When you look at [terraform's docs for security group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html), you can see that there is an option to define a `security_groups` argument inside the ingress/egress security rules.

It seems quite strange to me, but maybe I'm missing something here.

[I saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416882/aws-security-group-include-another-security-group) but there are no real world use cases mentioned.

My question is: In which cases we'll want to use this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this syntax to apply those ingress/egress rules to any infrastructure that belongs to a particular security group.

This Terraform code, for example:

```
ingress {
    from_port = "80"
    to_port   = "80"
    protocol  = "tcp"

    security_groups = [
      "${aws_security_group.elb_sg.id}",
    ]
}
```

will allow HTTP access to any infrastructure that belongs to the `elb_sg` security group. This is helpful if you've got a large amount of infrastructure that needs to have the ingress/egress access and don't want to name all of the parts individually.

Another example: you could create a security group for an Elastic Search cluster, and then state that all elements of an EC2 app server security group should have ingress/egress access to that cluster by using this syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Adil B, in your example, if all EC2 instances share the same security group, it means they share the same inbound rule. so i didn't understand what did we save here?

Comment: This syntax will let you define an egress rule without knowing the actual CIDR blocks or IPs of the infrastructure itself -- let's say I didn't have static IPs for my EC2 instances but still wanted to allow all of them to access my Elastic Search cluster.

Comment: Do you have another example - lets say an ALB in front of some some backend? could that be useful there?

Comment: Yes - you could create a security group for your ALB and allow any infrastructure in that group ingress/egress access to certain ports on your backend, for example.

Comment: Though I'd mostly use this syntax if I had an SG with many infrastructure pieces in it and wanted to allow all items in the SG to ingress to items in another SG - the ALB example would likely just have one item in its SG.